Normal approximation to Poisson weighted sum
I am trying to come up with a way to approximate the sum given below by a normal distribution.
$$ P(F| \overline{n}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(F|n)P(n|\overline{n}) $$
F is the sum of IID random variables sampled from a truncated Pareto distribution with finite mean and variance (the exact form is not that relevant with this knowledge) and P(n) is a poisson probability with rate $\overline{n}$
What I have tried so far:
I have applied the central limit theorem to P(F|n) which gives a normal distribution dependent on n, I think this is valid because weighting this with the poisson term reduces the impact of the low n terms where the CLT does not hold, however this gives a distribution which is no longer normal.
I was also thinking if I can approximate the sum by just saying
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(F|n)P(n|\overline{n}) \approx P(F|n = \overline{n}) $$  for n large since the mean of the Pareto is small in my model (approx 0.3).
Im really not sure how to go about this approximation, any help would be greatly appreciated.
